# How to identify the URL mapping for invoking Spring web flow

Tags: spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I have just started with Spring Web Flow. I have a basic doubt. In case of Spring MVC, the @RequestMapping contains the URL mapping, say for eg, @RequestMapping("/home"), this means, when the URL nodeContent is /home, the Contorller with @RequestMapping("/home") will be delegated by the dispatcher servlet. In case of Spring Web Flow, how is this mapping done? I mean, how do we even identify the request URL? is it the flow-location id in flow-registry? Basically, I want to know how to identify that when a Spring web flow is invoked based on what kind of URL request? eq- "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask", if this URL has to invoke a flow, how is the mapping done with the URL /ask.
Please can anyone answer this?

Answer (score 0):

The main thinks is, there are two beans which is complete the mapping.
First of all,

**FlowHandlerMapping :** in general, DispatcherServlet know the request mapping by handler mapping, but in WebFlow, FlowHandlerMapping helps DispathcerServlet to know the mapping. Basically it's "flow-registry". When hit the url, then it's get the url with the id. now it's ready to execute the flow.

**FlowHandlerAdapter :** When the executable flow url is ready then it's try to load the flow file with id like

> configure-flow.xml

Once you successfully get the path then flow will start. The flow will continue until **view-state** to **end-state**.

Maintain the order of your view page, because next flow will come in order.
If you have any question, leave in comment section.

Comment: this is not much useful.
what does this mean "When hit the url, then it's get the url with the id. now it's ready to execute the flow"